# jsMovie: not playing sequence

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a test with the jsMovie sequence player, a jQuery plug in that plays a sequence of jpegs to simulate animation. But though I can set options and log them and I get no errors I am also not getting any animation. Here's my code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.jsmovie.1.4.3b.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.movie').jsMovie({
        sequence : '26_01_010_####.jpg',
        folder : 'images/animation/26_01_010/',
        width: 480,
        height : 350,
        grid : {width:480, height:350, rows:1, columns:1},
        loader : {path: 'images/loader2.png', width: 50, height: 50, rows: 4, columns: 4},
        from : 1,
        to : 20,
        playOnLoad : false
    });

    console.log(_settings);

});
</script>

 </head>

<body>


    <div class="movie" style="width: 480px; height: 350px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my log output:

```
clipQueue : []
folder :"images/animation/26_01_010/"
fps : 12
from : 1
grid : Object { width=480, height=350, rows=1, more...}
height : 350
images : ["26_01_010_0001.jpg", "26_01_010_0002.jpg","26_01_010_0003.jpg", 17 more...]
loadParallel : 1
loader : Object { path="images/loader2.png", width=50, height=50, more...}
playBackwards : false
playOnLoad  : false
repeat : true
sequence : "26_01_010_####.jpg"
showPreLoader : false
step : 1
to :20
verbose : true
width : 480
```

Am I targeting the div incorrectly? There's not a lot of documentation on the plugin page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to actually play the movie because your playOnLoad setting is false...

Add the following line above your console call.

```
$('.movie').jsMovie('play');
```

Comment: I should of put this in my question but even with $(.movie).jsMovie('play') it wasn't playing.